# Python: Why am I getting different sorted results

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function where is take a dictionary who's values are tuples and sort them by the values in the tuple. However I am getting confused.

If I run

```
return sorted(mydict.values(), key=lambda x:x[0])
```

it returns everything in the order I want it except it doesn't return the dictionary keys with it, which I need.

So I tried running this:

```
return sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

but the ordering becomes different.

What is the difference between this two calls as far as ordering goes?

Comment: what does `values` do? what does `items` do? what is there in `x[0]` when x is an element of `values`? what is there in `x[1]` when x is an element of `items`?

Answer (score 1):

The first only sorts by the *first* element of the value whereas the second sorts by the *entire* value. If you want the same results then you need to either remove the `key` argument on the first or amend the `key` argument on the second to additionally access the first element.

Answer (score 1):

As described by Ignacio, you are sorting by the entire value of Items. You can sort either by the key or the value by using the code snippet below:

```
import operator
dict = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}

print "Unsorted : %s" %  dict.items()

print "Sorted by key : %s" % sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

print "Sorted by value : %s" % sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```